# android.support.v7.widget.SearchView doesn't display results

Tags: android, searchview

I want to use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView but to be in layout. I am using the Filter and in publishResults I am getting data but it is not displayed. Here is my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contactPickerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/addressSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

            android:hint="@string/enter_recipients"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#444444"/>
       <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_icon"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I have the following:

```
addressSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.addressSearchView);
doSearch(addressSearchView);
private final void doSearch(final SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And in the filter:

```
@Override
public final Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence){
            getContactList();
            final String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filteredContacts = contacts;
            } else {
                final List<ContactModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final ContactModel contactModel : contacts) {
                    if 
    (contactModel.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                        filteredList.add(contactModel);
                    }
                }
                filteredContacts = filteredList;
            }
            final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredContacts;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults 
    results) {
            filteredContacts = (List<ContactModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

I am getting results in the publishResults method but nothing is displayed. And I cant use the menu bar in this case.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Yes I have tried and as it is mentioned the filteredContacs has results but nothing is displayed.

Comment: I am using adapter that is implementing Filterable:




    public final class SmsConversationAdapter extends
        RecyclerViewAdapter<SmsMessageViewHolder, 
    SmsMessageModel> implements Filterable{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am new in android I didn't even know that the searchview component is only for search. Display of the results is suppose to be in ListView (at least in my scenario) and to create one ListViewAdapter. What helped me and can help other guys is this:

http://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview

It is the last example you just need to handle the visibility of the listview according to the request.